# node-gyp build error on centos

Tags: python, c++, linux, node.js

I am using Centos 6.6 installed on the server and trying to use node-gyp but I get a error when I am using the command node-gyp build, the python version I am using is 2.7.8 and GCC C++ compiler. The Error I get is mentioned below.

```
 # node-gyp build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.35 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory `/root/build'
make: *** No rule to make target `Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o', 
needed by `Release/obj.target/binding.node'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/root/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-
gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /root
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Did you try `node-gyp rebuild`? That essentially does the same as `node-gyp configure && node-gyp build`.

Comment: I get the following error make: Entering directory `/root/build'
make: *** No rule to make target `Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o', needed by `Release/obj.target/binding.node'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/root/build'

Comment: gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: I even tried sudo node-gyp build and also sudo node-gyp rebuild but I get the same error

Comment: Are you executing `node-gyp rebuild` in your project's root directory, where `binding.gyp` is?

Comment: Yes I am executing it from root directory and the binding.gyp is in the root folder, but I have also have the binding.gyp in node directory, I also tried to execute the node-gyp rebuild from node directory also

Answer (score 0):

You need to update node-gyp: `sudo npm update -g node-gyp`

Answer (score 0):

I have installed updated g++ with devTool

> sudo yum install --skip-broken devtoolset-3
>   sudo yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
>   sudo source /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/enable

And then it work ! ;)

> sudo npm --loglevel verbose --unsafe-perm i ursa